# [table].[field] vs table.field difference?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I don't quite understand the difference between, for example:

```
SELECT [Products].[ID], [Products].[ProductName] FROM Products ORDER BY [ProductName];
```

compared with

```
SELECT Products.ID, Products.ProductName FROM Products ORDER BY ProductName;
```

Can someone give me some insight please? The query produces same result for me.

Comment: The []'s are Microsoft's way for delimited identifiers. (Can be reserved words, or contain odd characters as %, ! and space.)

Comment: I see, so as long as I keep my tbl/field names without spaces and special charasters, I should be fine without having to use []? What is better practise? To use [] everywhere or only when needed?

Comment: I guess it's good practice to use them, but the code becomes slightly harder to read.

Comment: @jarlh While I'm not disagreeing, why would it be considered good practice?  Wouldn't using them in places that don't need []'s require more computing power for them to be interpreted, if even slightly?

Comment: @Newd, the major reason is forward compatibility. For example the keyword STATE was not reserved in SQL-92, but in SQL-99. So applications with a STATE column could quit to work when upgrading the dbms server. If [STATE], or "STATE", was used there were no problems!

Comment: Interesting point, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a programming language a variable name must be unique throughout its context and cannot have **Spaces**.

```
VariableA is valid
variable b is not valid
variable_b is valid
```

Some languages are even case sensitive.

```
variableA is valid
VariableA is valid and different from variableA
```

On the other hand MS ACCESS allows free formatted names for it tables, queries, forms etc. This means you could have a table called

```
This is a fruit table
```

to identify "this is a fruit table" as one word/item Access somehow needs to evaluate/know that the variable name is one word or its a variable name and not a text. Therefore Access uses [] to encapsulate the word so it can evaluate its content.

if you follow a most desired coding style you would name your tables with prefix such as tbl_fruits, frm_fruits, qry_view_fruits which will help you as well as Access to understand what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

If you use brackets around the names you can use reserved words like `order` for a table or colum name or names with spaces and such.

But you only need to apply the brackets on those but can apply it on all if you like.